# encode and decode alphanumeric value in php

Tags: php

```
function toChars($number) {
   $res = base_convert($number, 10,26);
   $res = strtr($res,'0123456789','qrstuvxwyz');
   return $res;
}

function toNum($string) {
   $res = strtr($string,'qrstuvxwyz','0123456789');
   $res = base_convert($string, 26,10);
   return $res;
}
```

i need this below id to convert into number and again need to decode with same id in php functions.

```
$alphanumeric_id="e0a65c50-0464-8605-25cd-558ba55b54ab";
```

any one can help me ..?

Comment: That looks like hexadecimal, not base 26. You also need to remove the `-` before converting it.

Comment: thanks Barmar. If i remove that - it should work . also i need same id while decode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this best is firstly base64 encode decode your value.

```
 $var = base64_encode('your_id');
```

and after that decode same variable where you need its orginal value.

```
$orig = base64_decode($var);
```

Comment: thanks jasbir . it works fine. but i need to convert that id into numeric not alpha numeric

Comment: hello prahap,  it is automatically convert system. so that there are no issue  in what type it convert. after eccode decode you got same what you have.